# Is the emphatic pronoun (itself) felicitous and grammatically used?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, intensive-prounouns

> "Stay there **itself**, I'll be there in 10 minutes."

Is the emphatic pronoun (itself) in the above structure felicitous and grammatically used?
If not, what other word would be appropriate there?

Context: My friend was waiting for me in the play-ground. He called me and asked to come to the play-ground and that was how I replied.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Itself* cannot be used to emphasize *there*. Itself is used this way with nouns and pronouns, but *there* is not a pronoun. It is a *pro-locative*: what it stands for is not a place but an expression such as a preposition phrase which locates something *at* that place.

What you should have said is

> Stay **right** there, I'll be there in ten minutes.

Comment: What if I tell, "You stay there itself, I'll be there in ten minutes." using a pronoun? @ StoneyB.

Comment: @KaranjeetKaur No. A *-self* word modifies the noun or pronoun which comes immediately before it; in your new sentence it *itself* can only be understood to modify *there*, which is unacceptable. You could say "Stay on the playground itself*, and that would be acceptable; you would be understood to mean actually on the playground, not somewhere near it. *Right* is the emphatic/intensive word to use with locatives: "Stay right where you are".

Comment: I'm kind of amazed you could even make sense out of this to tell what was really meant.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Ya gotta sorta squint at the question and ask yourself *How might this have been taught to make OP *think* this could be right?*

Comment: @KaranjeetKaur Off-topic, but *tell* is a transitive verb and requires an object like "What if I tell *someone*"

Comment: @Muhd You're half right -- *tell* is ditransitive and ordinarily requires **two** objects. What's missing in Karanjeet's comment is the indirect object; the sentence in quotes is the direct object.

Comment: @StoneyB That makes sense. Though, he probably should have used *say* instead now that I think about it.